# Stream a video in Azure Blob Storage to my PYQT5 python application

Tags: python, pyqt5, azure-blob-storage, video-streaming

I am trying to play a video which is stored in my Azure Blob Storage in my PYQT5 Application. I don't want to have it downloading locally. I did quite a bit of searching and found out you can do download_blob().read() or readall() or readinto() and this allows you to read it into the memory without having to download the actual file.

I tried using .read() .readall() and readinto() but not completely sure of what I am doing. I want the user to be able to watch the video as soon as it has been selected. I experimented with IOBytes but no avail. I also tried using the PYQT MediaContent widget and tried set_media().

```py
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QBuffer, QUrl
from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient

class VideoPlayerWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Initialize Azure Blob Storage client
        connection_string = "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountNameN/GrGcA==;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
        self.blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connection_string)
        self.container_name = "testing"
        self.video_path = "video/short-test-92734b6d9f2e/out_0.mp4"

        self.setWindowTitle("Azure Video Player")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)

        # Create layout
        layout = QVBoxLayout()

        # Create video widget
        self.video_widget = QVideoWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.video_widget)

        # Create play button
        self.play_button = QPushButton("Play")
        self.play_button.clicked.connect(self.play_video)
        layout.addWidget(self.play_button)

        # Set layout
        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

        # Initialize video player
        self.media_player = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.media_player.setVideoOutput(self.video_widget)

    def play_video(self):
        # Get video blob from Azure Blob Storage
        blob_client = self.blob_service_client.get_blob_client(container=self.container_name, blob=self.video_path)

        print("WAIT")
        # Download video content into memory
        # video_data = blob_client.download_blob().readall()
        print("WAIT")

        # Create a buffer from the video data
        # buffer = QBuffer(video_data)
        # buffer.open(QBuffer.ReadOnly)


        videoUrl = QUrl.fromLocalFile('azureBlobVolume/out_0.mp4')
        mediaContent = QMediaContent(videoUrl)
        self.media_player.setMedia(mediaContent)
        # Set media content to media player and play
        # self.media_player.setMedia(QMediaContent(), buffer)
        self.media_player.play()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = VideoPlayerWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Here is the code I was playing around with. As you can see above I tried reading the video from a buffer as well.

Comment: The buffer attempt will (theoretically) only work after `readall()` ends, which I'm assuming will completely block until the whole download has completed, but I'm only making an assumption as I've never used azure. As far as I know, it may even be an asynchronous request, making the result (possibly, the `download_blob()` object) invalid, because you're assigning the `video_data` reference to the result of `readall()`, which may not use object chaining. The other attempt is inappropriate unless you *do* have a **physical** `out_0.mp4` file within `azureBlobVolume/` in the *current* directory.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to play a video that is stored in my Azure Blob Storage
> in my PYQT5 Application. I don't want to have it downloading locally.

You can use the code below to play a video file from Azure Blob Storage without downloading it locally in your PYQT5 Application.

**Code:**

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QPushButton, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtMultimedia import QMediaPlayer, QMediaContent
from PyQt5.QtMultimediaWidgets import QVideoWidget
from PyQt5.QtCore import QBuffer, QUrl

class VideoPlayerWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.setWindowTitle("Azure Video Player")
        self.setGeometry(100, 100, 800, 600)
        layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.video_widget = QVideoWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.video_widget)
        self.play_button = QPushButton("Play")
        self.play_button.clicked.connect(self.play_video)
        layout.addWidget(self.play_button)
        central_widget = QWidget()
        central_widget.setLayout(layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(central_widget)
        self.media_player = QMediaPlayer(None, QMediaPlayer.VideoSurface)
        self.media_player.setVideoOutput(self.video_widget)

    def play_video(self):
    
        # Blob URL + ?SAS token (if your storage account container is private)
        blob_url ="https://venkat789.blob.core.windows.net/demo/sample-file-sd.mp4?sp=r&st=2024-02-21T06:56:05Z&se=2024-02-21T14:56:05Z&spr=https&sv=2022-11-02&sr=b&sig=FcQr%2B5jJssI8Ijxxxxxxxx"
        print("WAIT")
        print("WAIT")
        content = QMediaContent(QUrl.fromUserInput(blob_url))
        self.media_player.setMedia(content)
        self.media_player.play()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = VideoPlayerWindow()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The code above plays a video from a URL with a SAS token. It creates a QMediaContent object with the URL and sets it to the media player. Finally, it plays the video using the media player.

**Output:**

[image]